# Can we have the audit log for admin portal and customer portal with audited gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to maintain the audit log for action performed on each model, i have same database for customer and admin portal but i can store the customer id. I can only store the user id and changes made by user only on admin side. Any idea how do i maintain the log for both in one table with proper information.
I am using the gem Audited to maintain the log.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of audited `Audit#user` is a [polymorphic relation](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/blob/7fd8334edf682ea994b6f84980ddd19303590071/lib/audited/audit.rb#L42), so you can safely store users/customers (as model) on both sides (assuming both apps have user and customer models).

Make sure same `audited` version is set up in both apps (but do not use the generators, copy generated files from admin portal to prevent migration conflict)

Comment: I have set the gem in both app can you elaborate more. @vasfed